# Почему не работает валидация номера телефона?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Ситуация следующая. Валидация номера телефона работает не до конца. Закомментирован код не решает моей проблемы. Если добавить свойство `minlength`, то даже при вводе хоть одного символа форма считается валидная. Если добавить свойство `number`, то даже если заполнить все символы, валидация проходить не будет. Помогите пожалуйста в решении этой проблемы.
[Форма в самом низу](http://webdevep.takercorporation.com/)

```js
// Validation input number phone
// https://github.com/RobinHerbots/inputmask
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input-tel').inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99");
});


// Validation form
// https://jqueryvalidation.org
$("#contacts-form").validate({

    rules: {
        input_name: {
            required: true
        },
        input_tel: {
            required: true,
            //minlength: 10,
            //number: true
        },
        input_email: {
            email: true
        },
        "contacts_check_accept[]": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
    },
    messages: {
        input_name: {
            required: "Это поле обязательно к заполнению",
        },
        input_tel: {
            required: "Это поле обязательно к заполнению",
        },
        input_email: {
            email: "Введите пожалуйста корректный e-mail"
        },
        "contacts_check_accept[]": "Согласитесь с Политикой конфеденциальности"
    },
    focusCleanup: true,
    focusInvalid: false,
    errorClass: "form__input_error",
    validClass: "form__input_success"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно решить с помощью добавления параметра "clearIncomplete". Примерно так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //$('.input_tel').inputmask({"mask": "(999) 999-9999"});
 $(".input_tel").inputmask("+7(999)999-99-99",{ "clearIncomplete": true });
   jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    //$('#myform').ajaxSubmit();
    alert('asd');
  },
  rules: {
    input_tel: {
      required: true,
     // number: true,
      //minlength: 3
    }
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="myform">
  <input type="text" class="input_tel" name="input_tel">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```